# How to use https in Vite with vite-plugin-mkcert?

Tags: https, vite

I'm trying to run my app on the local environment with https.

I'm using [vite-plugin-mkcert](https://github.com/liuweiGL/vite-plugin-mkcert).

vite-config.ts:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc";
import mkcert from "vite-plugin-mkcert";

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    https: true,
  },
  plugins: [react(), mkcert()],
});
```

And I'm getting error after `npm run dev`:

```
error when starting dev server:
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/Users/{username}/.vite-plugin-mkcert/mkcert'
```

and after re-run `npm run dev`:

```
error when starting dev server:
Error: Command failed: "/Users/{username}/.vite-plugin-mkcert/mkcert" -CAROOT
/bin/sh: /Users/{username}/.vite-plugin-mkcert/mkcert: is a directory

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:419:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:449:11)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:320:12)
```

`Node: 18.13.0`
`Vite: 4.1.0`
`vite-plugin-mkcert: 1.13.2`
`macOS`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same problem.

I don't know what is causing the issue, but uninstalling (AND removing the `.vite-plugin-cert`-directory from home `~`) and reinstalling an earlier version `1.10.1` seems to have fixed this for me.

try: 
`npm i vite-plugin-mkcert@1.10.1 -D`